# Why i have to enter one more number before getting output on console screen?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int array[2][2];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (j=0;j<2;j++){
            scanf("%d ",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I want to get array print on screen as soon as i provide all elements and press enter, but i have to provide one more number to get output printed on screen ? Why ?

Comment: Buffering! Add a newline or call `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: `scanf("%d ",&array[i][j]);` -> `scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);` and  write `printf("\n");` before `return(0);`

Comment: or input E.g `1 2 3 4;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A space in a format specifier can skip any number of white-spaces.
Change

```
scanf("%d ",&array[i][j]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
```